# How do I capture a substring in a Visual Studio find and replace?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012

I want to do a find and replace in a HTML document in Visual Studio.  I have looked up the syntax, and placing a pattern inside parentheses captures and implicitly numbers the substring.  This works fine.

The problem is that I then want to use the captured substring in a replace, but the replace input box appears to have no knowledge of the numbered substring captured in the find.

In find, I had `\$([a-zA-Z]+)` to capture all dollar symbols followed by one or more letters. I want to replace the dollars with an apostrophe followed by the letters that were captured in the find.

Can anyone tell me how to do this, please?  It seems a *huge* limitation to me that the capturing of substrings is not preserved from the find to the replace.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex, `\$(\w+)`, it's pretty much the same as yours but a little bit shorter.

Then type this for replacement `'$1`. `$1` is the first capture group, i.e. the text.